# I want to download an audio from the server

Tags: android, audio, download

```
private void doFileDownload() throws Exception {

    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    BufferedOutputStream out = null;

    String url = "http://www.jimsonmok.com/server/uploads/";        //input
    String file = "/sdcard/Shek Kip Mei MTR Station Exit A.3gp";    //output

    try{
        url += URLEncoder.encode("Shek Kip Mei MTR Station Exit A.3gp");
        URL download = new URL(url);
        URLConnection downloadConnection = download.openConnection();       //set up connection
        in = new BufferedInputStream(downloadConnection.getInputStream());
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        int contentlength = downloadConnection.getContentLength();      //getting the length of the file
        for(int counter=0;counter < contentlength;counter++)         //storing the binary I/O file
        out.write(in.read());
    }catch(IOException e){

    }

    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

I am trying to download an audio from the server using an android phone.
The code above I am using does not work in android.
Does anyone know the reasons?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean with "does not work"? Which Android version?

Comment: What exception does it throw ?

Comment: "does not work" means I can't download the audio using these code. I am using Android 2.1 version.